# Static pages in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I read many posts on how to create a static page like About or Contact using CakePHP but still my page does not appear. Is there anything I missed? Please help since I started CakePHP today and I may have done some small mistake. Thanks. This is what I did.

1. Create about.ctp inside View/Pages/
2. Create route for the page
       `Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));`
3. Link to page in my default.ctp layout
   `<a href="<?php echo Router::url('/about'); ?>">About</a>`

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? if you go to `www.web.com/about` you don't see your page? or if you press the link (in 3) ) it takes you somewhere else?

Comment: when I press the link url changes to www.web.com/about but the page does not load.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! btw. the files should be in `/View/Pages` with a capital `P`.

Comment: Ah yes it's a mistake here and I corrected it. I use version 2.4.6 (latest stable)

Comment: What you've described is the correct way, it works fine for me. Make sure [**debug mode**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration) is enabled (`debug` should be `1` or `2`), try again and check the logs (`app/tmp/error|debug.log`) if you don't receive any error. Also check whether you can see the home page (`/pages/home`)?

Comment: try with debug mode set to 2 in core.php

Comment: what do you mean with 'dows not appear'? What exactly do you get? An error? A blank page?

Comment: Not a blank page. My default layout appears. Anything else I have put in about page does not appear.

Comment: do you have display.ctp in Views/Pages ?

Comment: there is no page called display.ctp only about.ctp and it is inside Views/Pages. display is the action I have in PagesController. Also I have default.ctp in Views/Layouts folder. @ndm my debug mode is enabled (2) and home page is also having this problem since it is also a page.

Comment: Sounds like something's pretty funked up. Such a problem is a little bit out of the scope of SO. I'd suggest you to do some further debugging, add debug output into the controller actions that should be invoked, hook in the controllers `beforeFilter` callbacks to check whether they are being invoked, compare to a fresh CakePHP installation and add your features one after another until it fails, etc... Could be something very simple, but it's impossible to tell from here.

Comment: yes @ndm I already continued with a fresh copy of CakePHP and now it is working. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add new action in pages Controller

try this

```
public function about(){

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also it is not necessary to rout display action always. Keep it simple you can do this as well

```
Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'about'));
```

Now you can view your about page at localhost/application/about

Comment: That's not how the [**pages controller**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html) works! It has an [**`display` action**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-PagesController.html#40-76) which does all the necessary wiring...

Comment: I did this now but there's no change. Still the url changes correctly but the page doesn't load. And yes.. Display action is there. Do I need to change anything? I still have the generated code by CAKE BAKE.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Still the wrong way of doing it, it will show the view, but it will lack the `page`, `subpage` and `title_for_layout` variables that are passed by `display`. What the OP posted is the correct and recommended way, it should work fine (for sure it does for me).

Answer (score 0):

you problem is here `<a href="<?php echo Router::url('/about'); ?>">About</a>`

Use this -

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('about', array(
                          'controller' => 'pages',
                       'action' => 'about'
));
```

or

`<a href="<?php echo Router::url('/pages/about'); ?>">About</a>`